# How to find users with a specific role in discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I am trying to make a discord bot that finds users with a specific role so it can do something with this group of users. I have written code to list all of the members in a server but I don't think this will help.

```
import discord
#some code
client = discord.Client()
#some code
client.run("my token")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following, use it like this `$get_members ROLENAME`

[ref for commands](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html)

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="$")

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Logged in as")
    print(bot.user.name)
    print("------")

@bot.command()
async def get_members(ctx,role_name):
    role = discord.utils.find(
        lambda r: r.name == role_name, ctx.guild.roles)
        
    for user in ctx.guild.members:
        if role in user.roles:
            await ctx.send(f"{user.mention} has the role {role.mention}")

bot.run("TOKEN")
```

Comment: bot is not defined. And when I change "bot" to "client". client does not have any attribute 'command'

Comment: I would suggest you move to using commands from discord extensions `from discord.ext import commands`  you can see my edited post to see how

Comment: bot is still not defined

Comment: sorry my bad, use you can use it like this `$get_members ROLENAME`

Comment: I just want to call it internally from the script, not from a bot command but I'm not sure what ctx is or how to pass it into the method

Comment: you would use the same code but instead of `ctx.guild` use `guild` which is `guild = bot.get_guild(ID_HERE)` and `ctx.send` to `channel.send` which is `channel = got.get_channel(ID_HERE)`